# Don't see any output

Tags: python, paramiko

Here is some code which doesn't give any output

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import paramiko

def remote_ssh(hostname, cmd):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname, username='blahblah', password='blahblah')
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    out =  stdout.readlines()
for lines in out:
    print lines

remote_ssh(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: You'll probably want to `return out` to use it in the code later. Also, your for statement is before you even call the function, so there's another problem.

Comment: Should the `for` loop be part of the function? Then correct the indentation, please

Answer (score 3):

When correctly indented, your code works for me:

**File `ssh.py`:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import paramiko

def remote_ssh(hostname, cmd):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname, username='changeme', password='changeme')
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    out =  stdout.readlines()

    for lines in out:
        print lines

remote_ssh(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

Called like

```
$ ./ssh.py localhost ls
```

lists the files in the home directory of the given user.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas , indentation did the trick